# How to import library modules to my namespace from another module?

Tags: python, import

I have written this function inside my utils module

```py
def megaimport(library_name):
    skip_modules = ["sys", "os", "dir_path"]
    exec(f"import {library_name}")
    for module in dir(eval(library_name)):
        if module.startswith("__") == False and module not in skip_modules:
            exec(f"from {library_name}.{module} import *", globals(), locals())
```

What I am trying to achieve is to import all functions to my namespace from any library with the following structure:

```
library:
- module1.py
   - function_1_1
   - function_1_2

- module2.py
   - function_2_1
   - function_2_2
```

just by running in my `notebook.ipynb`:

```py
from utils import megaimport
megaimport("library")

function_1_2()
function_2_1()
... etc
```

The idea is to dynamically call `from library.module1 import *`for every module in a library.
When I do this the function runs without errors but I when I call the functions they have not been imported properly. However, if I define the function in my code and run it it works as expected.

**How can I import all the functions into my current namespace?**

I am aware that importing everything like this is bad practice but for me it is convenient when working with jupyter notebooks.

My `notebook.ipynb` and `utils.py` live in the same directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after trying for a while I realised that I should pass `globals()` as a parameter to the function and pass it over to the `exec` in order to make it work in my namespace.

The function now looks like this:

```py
import importlib
def megaimport(globals_dict, library_name):
    skip_modules = ["sys", "os", "dir_path"]
    mod = importlib.import_module(library)
    for module in dir(mod):
        if module.startswith("__") == False and module not in skip_modules:
            exec(f"from {library_name}.{module} import *", globals_dict)
```

And it can be called just by:

```py
from utils import megaimport
megaimport(globals(),"library")
```